# Is photodiode detects all type of lasers?

Tags: photodiode, laser

My question is simple but I cannot find answer. does Photodiode circuit detect all type of lasers? for example laser pointer?

Comment: Different photodiodes are 'tuned' for different wavelengths of light. The material they're packaged in also determines which wavelengths are even 'allowed' through to the actual photodiode.

Comment: Literally just googled photodiode + laser and 3 of the first five articles had info on what type of photodiode to use for what wavelength. My results might be skewed because I look up semiconductor devices all the time but still... We are not here to google for you.

Comment: They are wavelength dependent. Some photo-diodes may be designed for specific wavelength and some may be designed for specific portion of a EM-spectrum. It is part of photoelectric effect. Different wavelength of light have different penetration level and thus producing different voltage across diode. Have a look at this link: http://www.osioptoelectronics.com/application-notes/AN-Photodiode-Parameters-Characteristics.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Any photodiode's datasheet should show the spectral sensitivity, as a plot of sensitivity against wavelength.

Any laser diode's datasheet should show the laser's output frequency or wavelength.

If the latter wavelength is within the range of wavelengths where the former has good sensitivity, then that photodiode can detect that laser.